# Can't post file data when request is sent over SSL

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, ssl

I have problems trying to use custom basic authentication module [similar to this](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/). The client uses `HttpWebRequest` class.

The client runs the following code:

```
void uploadFile( string serverUrl, string filePath )
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.
        Create( serverUrl );
    CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
    cache.Add( new Uri( serverUrl ), "Basic", new NetworkCredential( "User", "pass" ) );
    request.Credentials = cache;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    request.Timeout = 60000;
    request.KeepAlive = true;

    using( BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader( 
        File.OpenRead( filePath ) ) ) {

        request.ContentLength = reader.BaseStream.Length;
        using( Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream() ) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while( true ) {
                int bytesRead = reader.Read( buffer, 0, buffer.Length );
                if( bytesRead == 0 ) {
                    break;
                }
                stream.Write( buffer, 0, bytesRead );
            }
        }
    }

     HttpWebResponse result = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
     //handle result - not relevant
 }
```

If the request is created for a URI starting with `http://` it works okay - a request reaches the server, the authentication module is passed the request, it replies with `WWW-Authenticate`, the request is repeated now with authentication parameters, the module validates it and it passes further.

If the request is created for a URI starting with `https://` it doesn't work. The initial request gets to the module and the module replies with `WWW-Authenticate`

```
void ReplyWithAuthHeader()
{
    HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    context.Response.AddHeader( "WWW-Authenticate",
       String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", "myname.mycompany.com"));
}
```

an an exception is thrown at the client with "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine." text.

I tried [System.Net tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dgorti/archive/2005/09/18/471003.aspx) and discovered that after sending the initial request the client gets back the following header:

```
Date: Fri, 04 Feb 2011 12:15:04 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

while when the URI started with `http://` the client received the following:

```
Content-Length: 1894
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 04 Feb 2011 12:12:11 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="myname.mycompany.com"
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

so clearly the `WWW-Authenticate` response is swallowed somewhere and doesn't reach the client.

Also if I exclude the code that writes the file data into the request it also authenticates okay.

How do I fix this? How do I make the `WWW-Authenticate` response get to the client?

Answer (score 0):

What are the http status codes returned from the server?
Is the certificate of the server valid?
Can you post the stack trace?

Try to disable your firewall and other networking tools like fiddler etc on your client.
Also try with the KeepAlive property to false.