# Exception:"The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly" When invoking two methods same object

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, cisco

I am having a problem that many people have experienced but all of the solution that are available online are specific to their scenarios. I have tried the suggestions available but still no luck wha I have tried was:

```
1.) req.KeepAlive = false;
2.) req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10; (this solved a different exception that I was getting)
```

I have two methods passing XML string to the server and getting responses back the two methods are:

```
public string userDeviceQuery(string userID)
    {
        string query = "xml=<query>";
        query += "<appInfo>";
        query += "<appID>" + appID + "</appID>";
        query += "<appCertificate>" + appCertificate + "</appCertificate>";
        query += "</appInfo>";
        query += "<userDevicesQuery>";
        query += "<userID>";
        query += userID;
        query += "</userID>";
        query += "</userDevicesQuery>";
        query += "</query>";

        using (Stream str = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            str.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(query), 0, query.Length);
        }

        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

        string stringResponse;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            stringResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        string result = parseDeviceQueryRes(stringResponse);
        return result;
    }
```

AND

```
public void logoutOfEM(string deviceName)
    {
        string lgRequest = "xml=<request>";
               lgRequest += "<appInfo>";
               lgRequest += "<appID>" + appID + "</appID>";
               lgRequest += "<appCertificate>" + appCertificate + "</appCertificate>";
               lgRequest += "</appInfo>";
               lgRequest += "<logout>";
               lgRequest += "<deviceName>";
               lgRequest += deviceName;
               lgRequest += "</deviceName>";
               lgRequest += "</logout>";
               lgRequest += "</request>";

         using (Stream str = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            str.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lgRequest), 0, lgRequest.Length);
        }

        WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            stringResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        string stringResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

They are both part of a class called EMAPI. I can use both methods just fine separately but if try to use them back-to-back with the same object representing EMAPI I get the exception described above. I am not sure what is causing the connection to close, I would like to be able to keep it open and close it using a de-constructor if possible.

For those who are curious this code deals with Cisco Extension Mobility API, first method queries the server to get a device you are logged in, second method logs teh user out of that device.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: On an unrelated note I would use stringbuilder for efficient when constructed huge + strings.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, why is StringBuidler better when concatenating strings?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-performance

Comment: Did you check the connection state after the first call. It may be case that connection is closed by remote server.

Comment: Oh wow, I have about 15 queries in my code using string, I will fix them all. That could solve the slowness that I am experiencing. Tahnks!!

Comment: @theusguy The connection is automatically closed after calling either method, thats why I am not able to call the second method. I am not sure why it is closing automatically. I can instantiate the EMAPI again and call the second method but there has to be a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a different HttpWebRequest for each method. You should not reuse the HttpWebRequest object for different requests. Check this: [Can I reuse HttpWebRequest without disconnecting from the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933450/can-i-reuse-httpwebrequest-without-disconnecting-from-the-server). Internally, .NET can decide to reuse the connection to the same server if possible, but the server can decide to close the connection after each request, even if you specify req.KeepAlive = true.

Also make sure you dispose/close your WebResponse object in your methods.

Comment: I only set it to false just to try suggestions from different threads, I tried both 'true' and 'false'

Comment: I updated my answer, you should not reuse the HttpWebRequest for different requests.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would be using the 'using' keyword around all of my IDisposables first off. Secondly looks like you are leave the StreamReaders open.

**Edit**

To answer you comment about using keyword.

Instead of this:

```
Stream str = req.GetRequestStream();
str.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lgRequest), 0, lgRequest.Length);
str.Close();
```

Write it this way:

```
using(Stream str = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    str.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lgRequest), 0, lgRequest.Length);
}
```

The using keyword will automatically handle all IDisplosable task for you.

I just noticed something your code and why I thought you weren't closing. You are calling close and then trying to ready the lines. This is a good example of why to get into the habit of using the 'using' keyword.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());
reader.Close(); //Calling CLOSE before trying to use the reader
string stringResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

**ANOTHER EDIT**

```
public void logoutOfEM(string deviceName)
    {
        string lgRequest = "xml=<request>";
               lgRequest += "<appInfo>";
               lgRequest += "<appID>" + appID + "</appID>";
               lgRequest += "<appCertificate>" + appCertificate + "</appCertificate>";
               lgRequest += "</appInfo>";
               lgRequest += "<logout>";
               lgRequest += "<deviceName>";
               lgRequest += deviceName;
               lgRequest += "</deviceName>";
               lgRequest += "</logout>";
               lgRequest += "</request>";
     using (Stream str = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
        str.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lgRequest), 0, lgRequest.Length);
    }

    WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

    var response = string.Empty;
    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        response = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }


}
```

Comment: I did close all StreamReaders but that didn't help I am not sure what you are refering to " using the 'using' keyword around all of my IDisposables first off"

Comment: That makes since why we should be doing this, but it still did not fix the problem, I have updated my code in the question

Comment: In your edited question you are still calling reader.Close() the trying to use the reader after you closed it in method logoutOfEM

Comment: its a different reader in both methods, i am creating a reader and closing it in both of them

Comment: Yes but you still not understanding. You are calling close, before doing the ReadToEnd() in the method logoutOfEM. I corrected it in my edit.

Comment: I am not calling Close() anymore, i switched them to use 'using' but still same exception, and its happening at str.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(lgRequest), 0, lgRequest.Length);

Comment: I made an update to your question, had some extra calls still.

Where is req defined?

Comment: req is a global HttpWebRequest that gets instantiated in teh constructor

Comment: I would probably create a new one before each method call not create 1 on instatiation and pass that into those methods as a parameter.

Comment: Yes that was the problem look at fcuesta answer. You should use a seperate HttpWebRequest for each one, I did not know that. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Cool beans. Well hope you learned other stuff other than your issue. :)

Comment: definitely, I am switching to use StringBuilder(), and using "using" is also important to handle disposing objects automatically, lots of lessons in one thread :)

Comment: :) Awesome. Take care.