# The connection was closed unexpectedly C# after a long running time

Tags: c#, webclient, system.net.webexception

Hi I was making a crawler for a site. After about 3 hours of crawling, my app stopped on a WebException. below are my code in c#. client is predefined `WebClient` object that will be disposed every time gameDoc has already been processed. gameDoc is a `HtmlDocument` object (from `HtmlAgilityPack`)

```
while (retrygamedoc)
{
    try
    {
        gameDoc.LoadHtml(client.DownloadString(url)); // this line caused the exception
        retrygamedoc = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        client.Dispose();
        client = new WebClient();

        retrygamedoc = true;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

I tried to use code below (to keep the webclient fresh) from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845429/1500457) answer

```
while (retrygamedoc)
{
    try
    {
        using (WebClient client2 = new WebClient())
        {
            gameDoc.LoadHtml(client2.DownloadString(url)); // this line cause the exception
            retrygamedoc = false;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        retrygamedoc = true;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

but the result is still the same. Then I use StreamReader and the result stays the same! below are my code using StreamReader.

```
while (retrygamedoc)
{
    try
    {
        // using native to check the result
        HttpWebRequest webreq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        string responsestring = string.Empty;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webreq.GetResponse(); // this cause the exception
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responsestring = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        gameDoc.LoadHtml(client.DownloadString(url));

        retrygamedoc = false;
    }
    catch
    {
        retrygamedoc = true;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

What should I do and check? I am so confused because I got am able to crawl on some pages, on the same site, then in about 1000 reasults, it cause the exception. the message from exception is only `The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.` and the status is `ConnectionClosed`

PS. the app is a desktop form app.

**update :**

Now I am skipping the values and turned them to null so that the crawling can goes on. But if the data is really needed, I still have to update the crawling result manually, which is tiring because the result contains thousands of record. Please help me.

**example :**

it was like you have downloaded like about 1300 data from the website, then the application stopped saying `The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.` while all your internet connection still on and on a good speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConnectionClosed` may indicate (and probably does) that the *server* you're downloading from is closing the connection. Perhaps it is noticing a large amount of requests from your client and is denying you additional service.

Since you can't control server-side shenanigans, I'd recommend you have some sort of logic to retry the download a bit later.

Comment: I was thinking about that too at first, I have a couple call of the `WebClient` and I tried to run it in debug mode. The result is the next same chunk of statements (but with different content of `url` variable) can be executed. That's what made me curious. Anyway I will try your solution and test with `Thread.Sleep` with longer duration.

Comment: I have tested again and again, it seems like the problem is really happened on the rapid connection causing the website stopped my program's `WebClient`. I will add an interval between every page and when the same exception happened. Thank you, marked as answer.

Comment: Further investigation shows that antivirus software can cause the same problem. I was running the software again earlier this day and it returns the same error while my connection is slow and the pause using `Thread.Sleep` is conducted in every error. Shutting down antivirus for a while made the code works just fine like magic.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error because it was returned as 404 from the server.